# How to build this rewrite rule in app.yaml?

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-app-engine, mod-rewrite, yaml

I want to migrate my **php**-webapp to Google App Engine. The Problem is, that I currently use a htaccess File to manage my rewrite rules. Generally the rules are simple, but I didn't know how to migrate one rule from htaccess to the app.yaml file.

The htaccess rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([-_0-9a-z]*)/$ product.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Should redirect `http://example.de/product/red-pants/` to `http://example.de/product.php?p=red-pants`

For me it is important that the URL looks like a folder.

I hope that there is simple and elegant solution for this.

I appreciate any help :) **Thanks!**

Comment: You can't do it directly in app.yaml, but you can do it through a small auxiliary PHP script -- see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/mod_rewrite (unfortunately my own PHP-fu is weak so I can't show you directly how to solve your specific issue, it apparently also depends on whether your PHP app code relies on `$_GET['q']` or the more modern preferred approach of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` so you might want to edit your Q to clarify that -- after which I'm sure some PHP expert can craft a fully spot-on answer!-).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$path = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
$product = $path[2];
```

And this in your `.yaml`

```
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```